# Auto Escaped Reserved by Latex Chars in Custom Env

Tags: pdftex, tex-core

I want to create a custom environment designed to handle chunks of text. (Not code, text.) Within this environment, how to make LaTeX to automatically escape all reserved chars (# $ % & { } _ ~ ^ \ ), to make it possible to quickly paste text? I want to be able to just copy-and-paste from web-browser, and not waste time manually escaping these characters with backslash.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! But neither `:` nor `/` are reserved in LaTeX.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am sorry for not-quite-correct question.

I want to create custom environment where all reserved characters are automatically escaped # $ % & { } _ ~ ^ \ . I want just copy-and-paste from web-browser and do not waste time with manual escaping by reverse slash char.